# Futura italics is not rendering on <h2> tags on latest version of Safari (wordpress site)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, safari

I'm working on a wordpress site and I have a very odd issue. The Futura italics aren't rendering correctly when I add `<em> </em>` inside `<h2>` tags. The code looks like this:

```
<h2>vaya <em> que se vaya</em> si que si</h2>
```

and the outcome is:

[image]

The weird thing is that, when I check the same on code pen, I don't get the same issue I'm seeing wordpress:

https://codepen.io/alehl/pen/XKOvxk

I've seen other posts and tried the fixes they suggest without any success. I wanted to check and see if anyone knew of any other alternatives to fix this issue.

Comment: These are the things I've added to CSS which make no difference on wordpress:  `font-weight: 700;`
  `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`
  `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`

Comment: what's wrong with the outcome image you posted?

Comment: @andi the Italics are supposed to be bold. They aren't supposed to look thin like that